# GTM with NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Having troubles registering route change events on NextJs (SSR enabled) app.
I am using the **History Change** event trigger in GTM.

Using the **react-gtm-module** to initialise the Google Tag Manager.

Issue: The event fires on mount, with route eg. www.site.com/product/123
But the event does NOT fire when from the page /product/123/ I navigate to a page like /product/124/.

Product page:

```
return (
<div>
  <div>{props.title}</div>
  <Link href="/product/[pid]" as={`/product/124`}>
    <a>Another product (should trigger event here, but doesn't)</a>
  </Link>
</div>
)
```

I have tried adding this to _app.js (componentDidMount)

```
     import Router from 'next/router';
      ...
      componentDidMount () {
      ...
      if (process.browser) {
      Router.onRouteChangeComplete = url => {
        window.history.pushState({}, document.title, url);
      };
    }
```

What is the proper way of doing this in NextJs?

Comment: for me i used react-gtm-module i included this in the _app.js and then i setup GTM to trigger on "page" AND "history" change. as it could be one or the other depending on how you have your app setup. but this works for me as required and fires on every view change etc.

Answer (score 5):

You have to inject your tag manager script on every page. Since _document.js is the wrapper for every page, you should add the GTM script to _document.js in the head section as follow:

```
<Head>
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-*****');`,
  }}>
  </script>
  ...
</Head>
```

Comment: but it is in injected via the react-gtm-module npm package, which I init. Otherwise I wouldn't get any events on first render

Answer (score 3):

These links don't necessarily help with the packages mentioned above, but **for other users arriving here later who want a solution without extra packages:**

[Here is an example repo from Next that shows how to implement GTM.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager)

**Attach listeners to route changes with `next/router` and call your GTM update handler:**

```
const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', gtm.pageview)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', gtm.pageview)
    }
  }, [router.events])
```

[Additionally, here is the new (since Next 11) `next/script` component that has APIs designed to simplify the use of inline scripts.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

Comment: work for me.

Improvement  up to 20 point