# How to add Google Tag Manager to a NextJS website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, next.js13

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68739242/667903) and [this article](https://morganfeeney.com/guides/how-to-integrate-google-tag-manager-with-nextjs) I've added a `<Script>` in order to add Google Tag Manager to my NextJS website:

`components/layout.tsx:`

```
 import React from "react";
 import Head from "next/head";
 import Script from 'next/script'

 <!-- skip some code -->

 <Head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.sanity.io/" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.sanity.io//" />
  </Head>
  <Script id="google-tag-manager" strategy="afterInteractive">
    {
      (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=%27+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxx');
    }
  </Script>
```

However, the script is not present on the front end.

`components/layout.tsx` is the only file on my website with a `<Head>` or `<head>`.

The Google Tag Manager `<noscript>` is present on the front end, used in `app/layout.tsx:`

```
 <body className="antialiased text-gray-800 dark:bg-black dark:text-gray-400">
    <noscript
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xxxx" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" />,
      }}
    />
```

so I know I've saved all changes.

Help appreciated.

**Update**

I am new to NextJS, and all of this code is from a NextJS/Sanity template, which works locally and on a Vercel staging site.

My only problem is not being able to load Google Tag Manager properly before publishing to my domain.

There is no `_app.js` in the project.

There is `/app/(website)/layout.tsx`:

```
import "@/styles/tailwind.css";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import { cx } from "@/utils/all";
import { Inter, Lora } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-inter"
});

const lora = Lora({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-lora"
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      suppressHydrationWarning
      className={cx(inter.variable, lora.variable)}>
       <body className="antialiased text-gray-800 dark:bg-black dark:text-gray-400" >
        <noscript
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxx" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" />`,
          }}
        />
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is `/app/(website)/providers.tsx`:

```
"use client";

import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

    export function Providers({ children }) {
      return (
        <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="light">
          {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

If I search VSCode for `RootLayout`, nothing calls it, so I am a bit confused about which is the main file.

If you'd like access to the Github repo, I can provide it.

Comment: You should check this out: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/next-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 21):

**Check out new [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries) Third-Parties Component**

After watching the **NextJS Conf2023**, they released `@next/third-parties` because of people reporting in the past months after they followed the **Google Analytics Documentation**, it made bad perfomance issues on Lighhouse.

After following [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries) documentation guide, I was able to fully setup Google Analytics on NextJs 14.

***1. To load Google Tag Manager for all routes, include the component directly in your root layout:***

`app/layout.tsx`

```
import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'

export default function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>{children}</body>
            <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-XYZ" />
        </html>
     )
}
```

***2. To load Google Tag Manager for a single route, include the component in your page file:***

`app/page.js`

```
import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'

export default function Page() {
    return <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-XYZ" />
}
```

***Note:***
This is the Official [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries) Documentation.

Comment: Tried it on a NextJS 14 project and got import errors,
This github issue showcaes the issue (it was automatically closed but still happening): https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58458

Comment: @DanielAviv I also encountered the import error - there's another open issue with additional info here (unresolved at time of writing): https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58697

Comment: It worked for me on one project but not another. But then https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58697#issuecomment-1830677388 helped that one.

Comment: For those getting errors I was going to mention to check your TypeScript configuration but @Ryan's comment has it covered.

Comment: I'm seeing `undefined` on `gtm.js?id=undefined` in the page source regardless of whatever value I'll pass to the `GoogleTagManager` prop `gtmId`.

Answer (score 7):

In your **_document.js** file which is located in /pages directory add below code. Also if there is no any **_document.js** file then please create it.

Now add the functionality of Google Tag Manager as :

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

function MyDocument() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
              (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
              new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
              j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
              'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=%27+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
              })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID');
            `,
          }}
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <noscript
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
              <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxx"
              height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
            `,
          }}
        />
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Now you can check the functionality is working or not and please let me know if it not works. I will surely help.

Comment: The NextJS/Sanity template didn't include `_document.js` and I don't want to complicate or break things by creating it. [Yilmaz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250406/667903) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from [how-to-setup-google-tag-manager-in-a-next-13-app-router](https://dev.to/valse/how-to-setup-google-tag-manager-in-a-next-13-app-router-website-248p)

```
// create a client component
"use client"
// you are using id=GTM-xxxx. no need for gtmId
import { gtmId, pageview } from "lib/gtm"
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import Script from "next/script"
import { useEffect } from "react"

export default function Analytics() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname) {
      pageview(pathname)
    }
  }, [pathname, searchParams])

  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV !== "production") {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <noscript>
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxx`}
          height="0"
          width="0"
          style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden" }}
        />
      </noscript>
      <Script
        id="gtm-script"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', "GTM-xxxx");
  `,
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

import this in your `RootLayout` component

Comment: Replacing `gtmId` with `GTM_ID` in the code above and using [this gtm.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager/lib/gtm.js) worked

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are actually using your layout in in your `_app.js` file:

```
// _app.js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Layout from './layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In your layout.tsx you can load the script as follows:

```
// layout.js
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.sanity.io/" />
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.sanity.io//" />
      </Head>
      <script
        id="google-tag-manager"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=%27+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxx');`,
        }}
      />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that I'm not using the [Next `Script` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script), because the docs don't seem to mention anything about using children with the component.

[Here is the full working example on Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-wjitgw?file=pages%2F_app.js,pages%2Flayout.js)

Also make sure you don't have any browser extensions enabled which remove tracking related scripts. You can test in a different browser or in incognito mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added an Update to my question with more detail (there is no `_app.js` in the project). Also, I couldn't see your change in `<script id="google-tag-manager"` in` `layout.tsx`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to add a Google Tag in Nextjs 13+ when using the app folder (instead of the pages folder):

Create a new component anywhere in your codebase for storing the Google tag script (for example components/GoogleAnalytics.tsx).

```
import Script from "next/script";

export const GoogleAnalyticsTracking = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
      <Script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-GOOGLEID" />
      <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {`
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'G-GOOGLEID');
        `}
      </Script>
    </>
 );
}
```

And then, in your app/layout.tsx file, simply import the component like this:

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { GoogleAnalyticsTracking } from '@/components/GoogleAnalytics'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Your app name',
  description: 'App description'
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <GoogleAnalyticsTracking />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

In my setup, I'm using Nextjs with CSR (client-side rendering) by using `"build": "next build && next export"` in package.json.
This solution was inspired by this other post:
[Inserting script in head section of Next.js using Script component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74592484/inserting-script-in-head-section-of-next-js-using-script-component/74607014#74607014)

Answer (score 1):

The [@magicul/next-google-tag-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@magicul/next-google-tag-manager) node package may have removed the need to build something yourself:

`app/layout.tsx`

```
import GoogleTagManager from '@magicul/next-google-tag-manager';
const RootLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <GoogleTagManager id="GTM-XXXXX" />
      {children}
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add Google Analytics to your Next.js app by using @next/third-parties/google library which is provided by Next.js.

1. **First of all open your analytics account and create new Google Analytics 4 property**. At the data collection step it will provide you a measurement id like (G-XXXXX). Copy this ID and open your Next.js project.
2. **Add Next.js third parties library to your project**

   yarn add @next/third-parties
3. **After import as per the NextJs documentation guide**

- To load Google Tag Manager for all routes, include the component directly in your root layout and pass in your GTM container ID:

`app/layout.js`

```
import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
      <GoogleTagManager gtmId="G-XXXXXXXX" />
    </html>
  )
}
```

- To load Google Tag Manager for a single route, include the component in your page file:

`app/page.jsx`

```
import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'
 
export default function Page() {
  return <GoogleTagManager gtmId="G-XXXXXXXX" />
}
```

4. Run your app and inspect. You will be able to see the script tag of google analytics in your page elements.

**Make sure to test data stream URL after code update in google analytics. It will take hours for receiving analytics.**

Answer (score 0):

Next 13 App Dir Solution
after days and reading many articles i share my solution, (i mention that before using this solution I took next__error in my production which made me frustrated because i use  tag straight in the layout.jsx for some reasons)
and mention that i use the package [GtmHandler](https://github.com/XD2Sketch/next-google-tag-manager/tree/main) for this issue but you can do it manually [like here](https://dev.to/valse/how-to-setup-google-tag-manager-in-a-next-13-app-router-website-248p)

let's start and create the instance in the components directory


app/components/GTMHandler.jsx

```js
"use client"

import GoogleTagManager from "@magicul/next-google-tag-manager"
import { Suspense } from "react"

const GTMHandler = ({ id }) => {
// id is passed from parent
    return (
        <Suspense>
            <GoogleTagManager id={id} />
        </Suspense>
    )
}

export default GTMHandler
```

then in layout.jsx use it


app/layout.jsx

```js
import GTMHandler from "../components/GTMHandler";


export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
let id = "YOUR__ID"
  return (
    <html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
      <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
          <GTMHandler id={id} />
      </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

the Suspense HOC caused my app do not crash in production and works properly

Answer (score 0):

***Here i found solution***

it worked for me guys

here where i get the solution

https://pavelbrecik.cz/the-easiest-cro-you-can-do-is-via-google-tag-manager.html

I added this code to layout.js

**Note: Dont forget add setTimeout**

```
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxx');

        // Additional event pushed after GTM initialization
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'afterLoad'});
      }, 1500);
    `
    }}>
    </script>
```